# OpenCV: detect text from multiple boundaries simultaneously

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm currently trying to write a script to detect text in an **OBS video stream** using **Python/OpenCV**.

From every n-th frame, I need to detect text in **several** specific boundaries (Example can be found in the attachment). The **coordinates** of these boundaries **are constant** for all video frames.

My questions:

- is OpenCV the best approach to solve my task?
- what OpenCV function should I use to specify **multiple boundaries** for text detection?
- is there a way to use a video stream from OBS as an input to my script?

Thank you for your help!

[image: Example:]

Answer (score 1):

I can't say anything about OBS but openCV + [Tessaract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract) should be all you need.  Since you know the location of the text very precisely it will be very easy to use. [here](https://nanonets.com/blog/ocr-with-tesseract/) is a quite comprehensive tutorial on using both, which includes bits on finding where the text is in the image.

The code could look like this:

```
img = cv2.imread("...") # or wherever you get your image from
region = [100, 200, 200, 400] # regions where text is
# Tessaract expects rgb open cv uses bgr
img_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

output = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_rgb[region[0]:region[2], region[1]: region[3]])
```

The only other steps that might be required are to invert the image in order to make it dark text on a light background. Those tips can be found [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality). For example removing the red background that is in one of the boxes you highlighted might help with accuracy, which can be achieved by thresholding on red values `img_rgb[img_rgb[...,0] > 250] = [255, 255,255]`.

As for reading your images in, [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61926994/1097517) might help.